# WPF Binding Rect Width and Height to the main Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I properly bind the width and height of a rect to the bounds of the dialog itself? So that the painted rectangle always covers the entire window's client space.

Right now anytime I use my binding code, which is currently commented out, it doesn't appear to resize the rectangle properly. It should show a large dialog with a transparent window cutout.

[image]

XML

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfSnipping.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSnipping"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="500" 
        Width="500"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        Topmost="True"
        Background="Transparent">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:RectConverter x:Key="RectConverter"></local:RectConverter>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Canvas >
            <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="White" Opacity=".3">
                <Path.Data>
                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,300,300">
                                <!--<RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="MainGrid" Path="Width"/>
                                        <Binding ElementName="MainGrid" Path="Height"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>-->
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,100,100">
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    </CombinedGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfSnipping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class RectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        #region IMultiValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, (double)values[0], (double)values[1]);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `Rect="0,0,300,300"', it should take all the space you want. Not sure to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` as these dependency properties are updated whenever the size of the `MainGrid` changes:

```
<RectangleGeometry.Rect>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
        <Binding ElementName="MainGrid" Path="ActualWidth"/>
        <Binding ElementName="MainGrid" Path="ActualHeight"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</RectangleGeometry.Rect>
```